# javascript in php onclick

Tags: javascript, php

```
$testquery = "INSERT INTO education(employee_id, education_type_id, institution_id, course_name, period_from, period_till, education_document_id) VALUES($row[0], 2001134, 2001142, $coursename, $teststartdateresult, $teststartdateresult, 2001149)";
```

How to correct write in `onclick: if(confirm("send result?"))` -> oci_execute else stay on page

```
$link = '<a onclick = "" href = "link='.$row[0].'" target = "_blank">Send result</a>';
```

Comment: Well have you tried it yourself already?

Comment: I am not positive, but it looks like you are trying to execute PHP code from the browser. That is not possible! Javascript runs on the browser and PHP runs on the Server. You may need to learn some AJAX for this or chnage the way the page works so it runs itself to execute the Oracle query

Comment: @RiggsFolly exactly, it's only possible with ajax?

Comment: Well its not possible to run a server based query from javascript on the browser, unless you send a request to a script on the server with all the parameters required by the script to update the database. You do this using AJAX mechanisms or a `<form>` on the page or a anchor link that contains all the parameters on the querystring

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = '<a onclick = "return confirm(\'Are you sure?\');" href = "link='.$row[0].'" target = "_blank">Send result</a>';
```

Comment: so can you explain what you did to deserve this upvote and where the OP messed up?

Comment: sorry i m not getting you.. @Fred

Comment: Code only answers are not that helpful, explain what OP did wrong / what you changed / added in order to make the code work.

Comment: can you explain what you did to deserve this upvote and where the person who posted their question contained propable syntax errors? I honestly don't know how else I can phrase this. This for the OP (person who posted the question (Original Poster)) and for future readers.

Comment: i have directly wrote the code in onlick whether we can also call give a function name in on click and then write a code in that function but its lengthy and meaning less, instead i wrote one line code which will throw a confirm box and i have wrote return keyword so if user will cilck ok then it will return true and will goes to specified url which exist in href

Comment: You really should be writing what is wrong in the OP's code, rather than writing your above comment. This, and again for the OP and for future visitors to the question/answer.

Comment: @Fred- ok i will take care of your suggestion, and i appreciate your advice.. ;)